# When to use "deiner"

Tags: pronoun

Hello just trying to figure out in the sentence "und das Rathaus in deiner Stadt?" doe the "deiner" have an "er" on the end to refer to the your is a man, as the article for "Stadt" is "die Stadt" and should make the "dein/deine" right?

Comment: A look at [wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/dein) or any decent dictionary may be enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

These three words are a prepositional attribute:

> in deiner Stadt

<sup>*Prepositional attribute are built the same way as prepositional objects. Objects and attributes are just attached to their environment in different manners.*</sup>

It consists of a preposition (*"in"*), a possessive pronoun (*"deiner"*) and a noun (*"Stadt"*). In such a group pronoun and noun always must be in the same grammatical case, which here is dative case. In other constellations you can have other cases. It is the preposition that dictates which case it has to be.

The preposition *"in"* comes in many different flavors:

1. **local**, referring to a **place** (at which place?)
   This variation needs to have the **dative case:**

   > masculine (*der Wald*): Ich bin *in **dem Wald.*** = Ich bin im Wald. (*I'm in the forest.*)
   > feminine (*die Stadt*): Ich bin *in **der Stadt.*** (*I'm in the city.*)
   > neuter (*das Dorf*): Ich bin *in **dem Dorf.*** = Ich bin im Dorf. (*I'm in the village.*)
2. **local**, referring to a **direction** (into which direction?)
   This variation needs to have the **accusative case:**

   > masculine (*der Wald*): Ich gehe *in **den Wald.*** (*I walk into the forest.*)
   > feminine (*die Stadt*): Ich gehe *in **die Stadt.*** (*I walk into the city.*)
   > neuter (*das Dorf*): Ich gehe *in **das Dorf.*** (*I walk into the village.*)
3. **modal** (In which manner/mood?)
   If someone is in a mood: dative case (*"modal place"*)

   > Wir sind *in **guter Stimmung.*** (*We are in a good mood.*)
4. **modal** (Into which manner/mood?)
   If someone turns into a mood: accusative case (*"modal direction"*)

   > Das versetzt uns *in **Angst und Schrecken.*** (*This puts us in fear and terror.*)
5. **temporal** (when? At which time?)
   needs dative case (*"temporal place"*)

   > Ich komme *in **einer Stunde.*** (*I'll be there in an hour.*)
6. **temporal** (Into which time?)
   needs accusative case (*"temporal direction"*)

   > Dieses Wetter gehört eigentlich *in **den Herbst.*** (*This weather actually belongs in the autumn.*)

---

In your phrase the part "in deiner Stadt" refers to a place (*where is the town hall located?*), so it is a local prepositional attribute that needs to have the words that describe the place in dative case.

Other cases are:

> Nominativ: deine Stadt
> Genitiv: deiner Stadt
> Dativ: deiner Stadt
> Akkusativ: deine Stadt

Comment: In *das Rathaus in deiner Stadt*, *in deiner Stadt* is not a prepositional object but an attribute of *das Rathaus*.

Comment: @RHa: You are right, I corrected this.

Comment: Awesome that makes sense thank very much.